# Java: BufferedImage INT_RGB Alpha?

Tags: java, image-processing, colors, bufferedimage

Is there any way to use alpha in a `BufferedImage` that uses INT_RGB? I'm using a 1D pixel array to render sprites onto the screen but I wanted to be able to use Alpha. Is there any way to mix the colors and achieve some sort of layer system like in photoshop?

I've been trying to create some custom alpha by mixing colors, but im not quite sure how to do that either.

This is what I have so far:

BufferedImage & Pixel array:

```
BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(width / scale, height / scale, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
int[] pixels = ((DataBufferInt)image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
```

Method used to render sprite:

```
public static void drawSprite(Sprite sprite, int coord_x, int coord_y) {
    int boundsX = (coord_x + sprite.width), 
        boundsY = (coord_y + sprite.height),
        index = -1, pixels[] = Screen.pixels;

    for(int y = coord_y; y < boundsY; y++) {
        for(int x = coord_x; x < boundsX; x++) {

            index++;

            if(Screen.pixels[x + y * width] == 0) {
                Screen.pixels[x + y * width] = sprite.pixels[index];    

            } else {
                int[] screenPixel = intToARGB(Screen.pixels[x + y * width]);
                int[] spritePixel = intToARGB(sprite.pixels[index]);
                int[] newPixel = new int[4];

                newPixel[0] = (screenPixel[0] + spritePixel[0]) / 2;
                newPixel[1] = (screenPixel[1] + spritePixel[1]) / 2;
                newPixel[2] = (screenPixel[2] + spritePixel[2]) / 2;
                newPixel[3] = (screenPixel[3] + spritePixel[3]) / 2;

                Screen.pixels[x + y * width] = Integer.parseInt((Integer.toString(newPixel[0]) +
                                                                 Integer.toString(newPixel[1]) + 
                                                                 Integer.toString(newPixel[2]) + 
                                                                 Integer.toString(newPixel[3])));
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: note the lack of A in TYPE_INT_RGB :) why not use TYPE_INT_ARGB ?

Comment: It uses up more resources, also it's not working with my pixel array. I would like to use RGB if possible

Comment: actually, it doesn't RGB uses 32 bit (4 byte) integers and just like ARGB. it just doesn't use the last byte. pushing a square peg into a round hole is never justified by "saving resources". if anything, a work around is going to be slower and more complex

Comment: if its not working its probably because you need to set the alpha of any new pixels you "draw" to 0xff. otherwise it's all transparent (which is what your code asked for).

Comment: Oh? It seems to use more cpu power for me... I usually get around ~3K FPS with TYPE_INT_RGB and ~2K With TYPE_INT_ARGB, also another problem is it doesn't really work for me. Like it renders black if the alpha is low. And in the sprite class im loading the pixels into an int with  alpha.

Comment: oh by resources I assume you meant raw memory. yes, on non-accelerated systems I can see how the alpha blending might be slower. so, in this case im not sure what you mean by "alpha". Do you want this image blended with another or the background?

Comment: or are you just trying to darken pixels so they appear fainter (blended) with a black background?

Comment: I want opacity like Photoshop offers with it's layers. So yeah I want to mix the colors so the color is darker

Comment: if you want to blend a set of images / layers just like photoshop, the best option really is ARBG. its slower, because its doing the blending. but nothing you can write using RGB will ever be faster than what the JVM and any hardware acceleration it has access to, can do.

Comment: Is there an article or tutorial on this somewhere? I've tried this but I haven't had any luck..

Comment: probably but nothing im aware of off hand. im guessing the slowest part of your code is the Integer.parseInt / Integer.toString in a tight loop. check out bit shifting for that stuff.

Comment: that doesnt even look correct. its not handing hex values properly. thats probably why everything is dark

Comment: Use ARGB. RGB doesn't have alpha. This is like asking how to have colors in a grayscale image.

Comment: Actually I think I almost got it, and im using TYPE_INT_RGB. Got transparency, the colors are just a bit messed up

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to use alpha in a `BufferedImage` that uses `INT_RGB`?

Short answer: No.

Long answer: No, a `BufferedImage` of type `INT_RGB` doesn't contain alpha (unless you redefine what R, G and B means, that is...). *But it's of course possible to correctly compose other types of `BufferedImage` with alpha (like `TYPE_INT_ARGB`, `TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR` or even `TYPE_BYTE_INDEXED` with alpha or transparent pixel in the `IndexColorModel`) onto a `BufferedImage` that uses `TYPE_INT_RGB`.* Maybe this is what you are trying to do?

Side note: Java2D already implements image compositing and different types of (Porter/Duff) alpha blending rules in the class `AlhpaComposite`. Using this class, you get possibly hardware accelerated alpha blending that is super fast. I don't understand why you want to re-implement this.